# On Click not updating the output of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text === 'Celsius' ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius');
  changeUnits();
});

function changeUnits(Temp, c) {
  if ($('.btn').text() === 'Celsius')   
    return Math.round((Temp - 273.15)*10)/10 + " &degC";
  else
  return Math.round(((Temp* (9/5)) - 459.67)*10)/10 + " &degF";
}
```

I am trying to use a button on click event to change the temp display, but it doesn't seem to work like this.  The function keeps seeing Celsius no matter what.  I tried $(this).html too.  The text of the button is actually changing, just the function isn't updating.  I tried running the change units function inside the the button click even as well and it still doesn't update.

What am I not understanding about this onclick event and how can I get it to work.

JS Code:

```
    var apiKey = "get your own key from http://openweathermap.org";

  function changeUnits(Temp, c) {
  if ($('.btn').text() === 'Celsius')   
    return Math.round((Temp - 273.15)*10)/10 + " &degC";
  else
  return Math.round(((Temp* (9/5)) - 459.67)*10)/10 + " &degF";
}

$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text === 'Celsius' ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius');
  changeUnits();
});

$(function() {
  var loc;
  //api call to get lat and long
  $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    loc = data.loc.split(",");

    //weather API call
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
      loc[0] + '&lon=' + loc[1] + '&appid=' + apiKey,
      function(weather) {
        var currentLocation = weather.name;
        var currentConditions = weather.weather[0].description;
        var currentTemp = changeUnits(weather.main.temp);
        var high = changeUnits(weather.main.temp_max);
        var low = changeUnits(weather.main.temp_min);
        var currentWind = weather.wind.speed;
        var currentWdir = weather.wind.deg;
        var sunRise = weather.sys.sunrise;
        var sunSet = weather.sys.sunset;
        var icon = weather.weather[0].icon;
        //set HTML elements for weather info
        $('#currentLocation').append(currentLocation);
        $('#currentTemp').html(currentTemp);
        $('#high-low').html('<span id="high">High: ' + high + '</span><br>' 
                            + '<span id="low">Low: ' + low + '</span>');
        $('#currentConditions').html(currentConditions);

        var iconSrc = "http://openweathermap.org./img/w/" + icon + ".png";
        $('#currentConditions').prepend('Outside the current conditions are <br><img id="weatherImg"src="' + iconSrc + '"><br>');
      });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript,width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="left"><h1 id="currentLocation">Your Current Location is  </h1></div>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="right"><a href="https://github.com/Maverick494"><i class="fa fa-github bigger_icon"></i></a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <h2 class="text-center content-title" id="currentTemp"></h2>
    <div class="content-body text-center">
      <p id="high-low"></p>
      <button data-text-swap="Fahrenheit" id="unitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Celsius</button>
      <p id="currentConditions"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have done every change I can think of.  console.log(el.text()) in the onclick clearly shows the text changing; but the function for changeUnits never seems to pick it up in the if statement when I run the function again during the onclick.

Comment: can you create a fiddle example link so that we can check the html part also. we can't able to reproduce your problem so that we can rectify it.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong why used class .btn instead use ID also, you will create circular dependency if you call it on button click

Comment: Where are  you getting your c and f parameters in the click function?

Comment: Added the pen to the original ask

Comment: I used the class because I only have one button for this simple project, but I updated it to ID for the button later and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Jackstien, no where; I based the onclick to update the text based on code from searches that showed that method on stackoverflow.  I picked f and c because of the first letters of the text. apparently using that method to change the text on the button isn't doing what I need it to do in terms of the html though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
var apiKey="get an openweathermap APIKey";    
var loc;
var lat;
var long;

var temp;
var high;
var low;
var icon;
//var wind;
//var windDir;
//var windSpd;

//api call to get lat and long
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
  loc = data.loc.split(",");
  lat = parseFloat(loc[0]);
  long = parseFloat(loc[1]);
  getWeather(lat, long);
  initGmaps(lat, long);
});

//api call to use lat and long to generate a map
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = '?key=AIzaSyDKgEmSnYmFmbhQVGY8K6NXxV5ym2yZXdc&callback=initMap';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initGmaps(lat, long) {
 var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: lat,
    lng: long,
    zoom: 14,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: "satellite",
  });
map.addMarker({
  lat: lat,
  lng: long
});
}

//using weather to get data and plug it into our page
function getWeather(lat, long) {
  var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
    lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=' + apiKey;

  $.ajax({
    url: api,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      temp = {
        f: Math.round(((data.main.temp * 9 / 5) - 459.67) * 100) / 100 + " °F",
        c: Math.round(((data.main.temp - 273.15)) * 100) / 100 + " °C"
      };
      high = {
        f: Math.round(((data.main.temp_max * 9 / 5) - 459.67) * 100) / 100 + " °F",
        c: Math.round(((data.main.temp_max - 273.15)) * 100) / 100 + " °C"
      };
      low = {
        f: Math.round(((data.main.temp_min * 9 / 5) - 459.67) * 100) / 100 + " °F",
        c: Math.round(((data.main.temp_max - 273.15)) * 100) / 100 + " °C"
      };

      windSpd = {
        f: Math.round((data.wind.speed * 2.23694)*10)/10 + " MPH",
        c: Math.round((data.wind.speed)*10)/10 + " M/S"
      };

      var windArr = ["N","NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE", "SE", "SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW"];

      var windDir = windArr[Math.floor(((data.wind.deg/22.5)+.5))]; 

      $('#currentLocation').append(data.name);
      $('#high').append(" " + high.f);
      $('#low').append(" " + low.f);
      $('#currentTemp').html(temp.f);
      $('#weatherDesc').html(data.weather[0].description);
      $('#windDir').html(windDir);
      $('#windDir').append('<span id="windSpd">' + windSpd.f + '</span>');            


      icon = data.weather[0].icon;
      var iconSrc = "http://openweathermap.org./img/w/" + icon + ".png";
      $('#currentConditions').html('<img id="weatherImg" src="' + iconSrc + '"><br>');
    }
  });
}

$('#currentTemp').on('click', function() {
  var current = $(this).data('nexttemp');
  $('#currentTemp').text(temp[current]);
  $('#high').html(high[current]);
  $('#low').html(low[current]);
  $('#windSpd').html(windSpd[current]);

  if (current == 'c') {
    $(this).data('nexttemp', 'f');
    return;
  }
  $(this).data('nexttemp', 'c');
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript,width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="navbar"><h4>Free Code Camp Weather App</h4></div>
    <div class="right"><a href="https://github.com/Maverick494"><i class="fa fa-github bigger_icon"></i></a></div>
  </div>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="col-lg-4" id="map"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h1 id="currentLocation">Your Current Location is </h1>
      </div>
      <h2 class="center-text content-title" id="currentTemp"></h2>
      <h3 id="caption">Click temperature to change Units</h3>
      <div class="center-text">
      <p class="oneLine" id="labels">High: <span id="high"></span></p>
      <p class="oneLine" id="labels">Low:  <span id="low"></span></p>
      </div>
      <p class="center-text" id="currentConditions"></p>
      <p class="center-text" id="weatherDesc"></p>
      <div class="windCompass col-lg-4">
        <div class="compass">
          <div class="direction">
            <p id="windDir"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="arrow ne"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,400,500,600);

body {
    background: url(http://eskipaper.com/images/pixel-backgrounds-1.jpg);
    background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Ranga, cursive;
}

h4 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: -7px;
  font-size: 1.05em;
    color: white;
}

#header {
    background: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #555555;
}

#header .left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

#header .navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
}

#header .right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.bigger_icon {
    margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}

#map {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#container {
    background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.6);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 24px auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#container .center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Ranga, cursive;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -230px;
}

#caption {
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    color: pink;
}

#labels {
    color: darkGrey;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.oneLine {
    color: darkGrey;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}

#high {
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
}

#low {
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
}

#currentConditions {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#weatherDesc {
    margin-top: -25px;
    color: white;
}

.windCompass {
    margin-left: 75%;
    margin-top: -20%;
}

.compass {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Dosis';
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
}

.compass:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    content: "N";
    font-size: 14px;
    top: -2px;
}

.compass .direction {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #f2f6f5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f5 30%, #cbd5d6 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2f6f5), color-stop(100%, #cbd5d6));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f5 0%, #cbd5d6 100%);
    background: o-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f5 0%, #cbd5d6 100%);
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.compass .direction p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -35%;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.compass .direction p span {
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: -10%;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Ranga, cursive; 
}

.compass .arrow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.compass .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.compass .arrow.nne {
    transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.ne {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.compass .arrow.ene {
    transform: rotate(67.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.e {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.compass .arrow.ese {
    transform: rotate(112.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.se {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.compass .arrow.sse {
    transform: rotate(157.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.s {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.compass .arrow.ssw {
    transform: rotate(202.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.sw {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.compass .arrow.wsw {
    transform: rotate(-114.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.w {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.compass .arrow.wnw {
    transform: rotate(-69.5deg);
}

.compass .arrow.nw {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.compass .arrow.nnw {
    transform: rotate(-24.5deg);
}
```

I ended up finding some Ajax and working with it to do what I expected the button to do.  While not a button, it does what is intended.  I also worked in changing the high, low, and wind speed to also change with the unit change.

I appreciate the help that everyone offered.

feel free to offer suggestions on the code as well for fixing the css for the compass gradient and making the stupid thing more responsive if you'd like. (The Map is not doing the responsive thing.

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the function,   read comments in code
Also you are not passing any information to the '.btn' in the function passed to the text method.

```
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  var text = function(f, c) {  // where are you getting your f and c parameters?
        console.log(f); // should be undefined
        console.log(c); // should be undefined
        return c === 'Celsius' ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius';
      }();
  console.log(text); // should be 'Celsius'
  $(this).text(text);   // changed from })  to }())
});


function changeUnits(Temp, c) {
  if ($('.btn').text() === 'Celsius')   //  change html() to text() as well
    return Math.round(Temp - 273.15) + " &degC";
  else
  return Math.round((Temp* (9/5)) - 459.67) + " &degF";
}
```

Additionaly you should use a ID to associate your button to do this

```
<input id='thisID'>
// then call it in javascript
$("#thisID")
```

Toggleing the button

```
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text === 'Celsius' ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius');
});
```

Comment: Well the f and c parameters, after looking, are coming from no where; that said the button text doesn't change without them in there. When I make the change from }) to }()) the on click no longer changes the button text.  I also must not have mentioned I tried .text() as well and it still doesn't work.  I can use ID I have an id for the button of "unitButton"

Comment: Also, do I need to pass anything to the button onclick?  I thought I was just reading what the button text is and updating the function based on that.  I guess I would need a way to re-run the changeUnits function in there. I have tried putting changeUnits() in the onclick a couple of times/places and it doesn't help

Comment: One more thing, if I go into my HTML and remove the word Celsius it changes.  So I know for a fact the change units function is working.  Its like the button text changing isn't actually changing in the HTML though.  So maybe that is the part that I have wrong.

Comment: Added the code pen for all the code to the original question

Comment: you are not changing the text.   try my editted version

Comment: I think that you want to toggle the text on the button,  so I will add some code for that too.

Comment: Yes, I copied the code to change the text on the button and tried to use that to make the change to the temperature reading on the page.  Apparently the code I copied doesn't do anything to the base HTML it just overrides what is shown on the button so the other function never sees an actual change to the button text in the HTML and it never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `html()` instead of `text()`. I assume you're looking for button text instead of html, so try this:

```
$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  $(this).text(function(f, c) {
    return c === 'Celsius' ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius';
  });
});

function changeUnits(Temp, c) {
  if ($('.btn').text() === 'Celsius'){
    return Math.round(Temp - 273.15) + " &degC";
  }else{
    return Math.round((Temp* (9/5)) - 459.67) + " &degF";
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it also didn't seem to work.  I will post what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think is your problem. I didn't get to test it because I need to get the weather API and stuff. By looking at your code, here is what I get.

When the page loads, you are getting weather data from OpenWeatherMap. However, you are not cashing this info in some sort of global variable in order for you to access it later. You have declared all your variables inside the ajax callback and you have no way of accessing them later.

Try to do this:

```
var currentTemp;
var high;
var low;

$(function() {
  var loc;
  //api call to get lat and long
  $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    loc = data.loc.split(",");

    //weather API call
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
      loc[0] + '&lon=' + loc[1] + '&appid=' + apiKey,
      function(weather) {
        var currentLocation = weather.name;
        var currentConditions = weather.weather[0].description;
        currentTemp = weather.main.temp;
        high = weather.main.temp_max;
        low = weather.main.temp_min;
        var currentWind = weather.wind.speed;
        var currentWdir = weather.wind.deg;
        var sunRise = weather.sys.sunrise;
        var sunSet = weather.sys.sunset;
        var icon = weather.weather[0].icon;
        //set HTML elements for weather info
        $('#currentLocation').append(currentLocation);
        updateDisplay();
        $('#currentConditions').html(currentConditions);

        var iconSrc = "http://openweathermap.org./img/w/" + icon + ".png";
        $('#currentConditions').prepend('Outside the current conditions are <br><img id="weatherImg"src="' + iconSrc + '"><br>');
      });
  });
});

function changeUnits(Temp) {
  if ($('.btn').text() === 'Celsius')   
    return Math.round((Temp - 273.15)*10)/10 + " &degC";
  else
  return Math.round(((Temp* (9/5)) - 459.67)*10)/10 + " &degF";
}

$('.btn').on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text === 'Celsius' ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius');
  updateDisplay();
});


function updateDisplay(){
      $('#currentTemp').html(changeUnits(currentTemp));
      $('#high-low').html('<span id="high">High: ' + changeUnits(high) + '</span><br>' 
                                    + '<span id="low">Low: ' + changeUnits(low) + '</span>');
}
```

I have introduced another function updateDisplay() to actually handle the changing of the displayed temps. As I said, I didn't get to test it. But I am pretty sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your script probably gets loaded before the DOM is ready.

What you want to do here is one of a few options:
1. Load the JS script tag at the end of the body.
2. Wrap your $('.btn').on(...) function with document.on('ready') event, so this code will only be triggered when the DOM is ready.